# What port is USB 1-1-port1

Tags: login

I cannot login to Ubuntu, everything starts okay, but I just return to the login after entering the correct password.

On entering tty there is a looping error:

USB 1-1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?

I have disabled all ports in the BIOS, and no peripherals work when I boot to login, as should be the case. I have also unplugged EVERYTHING so as to isolate issues. Clearly a hardware issue. There is a latency issue in the bios too. What port is USB 1-1-port1 typically?

Comment: Laptops may have internal USB ports, like cameras. Please use Ctrl+Alt+F4 and try to login in text mode.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I did not find out how to eliminate the USB device of your config.
But maybe this helps to find out more about the device (in case you get hold of a text terminal):

You could try to `cat  /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/product`. This would output the name of a connected device.

Or if this file is not present, get the vendor and product ids with:

`cat  /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/idVendor`
and

`cat  /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/idProduct`

This will output two hex numbers, for example vendor 8087 and product 0032.
You can use this numbers form with them a string like
`USB\VID_8087&PID_0032` and search for that on the internet. You will most like find out that way what the device in question is.

Whatever your approach, is investigating content in `/sys/bus/usb/devices` + subfolders might give you more information.